# SQL select database name from column

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have this table

[image: tbl1]

i want to select a data from multiple databases, the database name is saved into a column dbname
so my select query must be somthing like this

```
select col,col1 from [dbName].tbl where .....
```

database name must be retrieved from the column dbName from tbl1
hope to be clear

Note:
I'am editing an already written query i need it to be a normal query written between code, I CAN'T USE STORED PROCEDURES

Comment: Dynamic SQL helps you

Comment: Also remember, dbo schema  usage and also not only dbo schema could be present in the Database

Comment: When connected to a database you should know which one, right? So simply select accodingly `WHERE dbName = 'Database Name' `. I expect the table to be present in all these databases, correct? So you don't need a qualifier: `from tbl`. Or, if it resides in a specific database, then name this: `from mydatabase.tbl`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write you dynamic query as follows.

```
Declare @query varchar(1000)
select @query= dbname from [table name] where [condition]
//Get the DBName on which you want to execute the query


Declare @str as varchar(1000)
set @str = N'select [column name] from [' + @query +'].[tbl] as A'
//.[tbl] is the name of the table in your database and in [column name] provide the list of columns

exec (@str)
```

Comment: my problem is that i'am editing an already written sql query, i can't convert it to dynamic query because it's really big one ! 29 union all and 19 inner join and 18 left outer join !! i need it to be a simple query written in code

Comment: @mothana in either case you have to modify your existing query. You shouldn't be afraid while doing that. Either fit in this code intelligently in your existing code, or show what is your code, and we will fit it in there..